# Linux image removal or installled failed

Tags: 14.04, apt, kernel, uninstall

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS i386. Currently installed linux-image-extra-3.13.0-153-generic.
From past few week I am dealing with this problem, but now the problem gets bigger...even I am not able to install any package from Ubuntu market/store. So far I have tried `-f install` to fix this and many commands like `clean` `--purge` `autoremove` `remove` `dpkg`.

#### result of sudo apt-get -f install

```
imtiyaz@Baka:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for imtiyaz: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-3.13.0-155-generic linux-image-3.13.0-161-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-162-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-155-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-161-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-162-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-163-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 7 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
21 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 562 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 486931 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-155-generic (3.13.0-155.205) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.13.0-155-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-155-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-155-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-155-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-155-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-155-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.13.0-155-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_bn5jf7/lib/modules/3.13.0-155-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_bn5jf7/lib/modules/3.13.0-155-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.13.0-155-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-155-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.13.0-155-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-155-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-155-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-155-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-164-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-164-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-163-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-163-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-160-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-160-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-157-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-157-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-156-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-156-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-153-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-153-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
usage: paste [-h]
paste: error: unrecognized arguments: -s -d  
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-155-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-3.13.0-155-generic (3.13.0-155.205) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-155-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-155-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-155-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-155-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-155-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-164-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-164-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-163-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-163-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-160-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-160-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-157-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-157-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-156-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-156-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-153-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-153-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
usage: paste [-h]
paste: error: unrecognized arguments: -s -d  
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-155-generic.postrm line 330.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-155-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-161-generic (3.13.0-161.211) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.13.0-161-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-161-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-161-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-161-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-161-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-161-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.13.0-161-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_JHFHuG/lib/modules/3.13.0-161-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_JHFHuG/lib/modules/3.13.0-161-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.13.0-161-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-161-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.13.0-161-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-161-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-161-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-161-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-164-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-164-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-163-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-163-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-160-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-160-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-157-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-157-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-156-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-156-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-153-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-153-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
usage: paste [-h]
paste: error: unrecognized arguments: -s -d  
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-161-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-3.13.0-161-generic (3.13.0-161.211) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-161-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-161-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-161-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-161-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-161-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-164-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-164-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-163-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-163-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-160-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-160-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-157-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-157-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-156-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-156-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-153-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-153-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
usage: paste [-h]
paste: error: unrecognized arguments: -s -d  
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-161-generic.postrm line 330.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-161-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-162-generic (3.13.0-162.212) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.13.0-162-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-162-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-162-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-162-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-162-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-162-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.13.0-162-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_N9RaU9/lib/modules/3.13.0-162-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_N9RaU9/lib/modules/3.13.0-162-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.13.0-162-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-162-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.13.0-162-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-162-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-162-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-162-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-164-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-164-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-163-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-163-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-160-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-160-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-157-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-157-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-156-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-156-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-153-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-153-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
usage: paste [-h]
paste: error: unrecognized arguments: -s -d  
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-162-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-image-3.13.0-162-generic (3.13.0-162.212) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-162-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-162-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-162-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-162-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-162-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-164-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-164-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-163-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-163-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-160-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-160-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-157-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-157-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-156-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-156-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-153-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-153-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
usage: paste [-h]
paste: error: unrecognized arguments: -s -d  
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-162-generic.postrm line 330.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-162-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-163-generic (3.13.0-163.213) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-163-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-163-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-163-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-163-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-163-generic
^[[1;2B^[[Arun-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.13.0-163-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-163-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.13.0-163-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-163-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-163-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-163-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-164-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-164-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-163-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-163-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-160-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-160-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-157-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-157-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-156-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-156-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-153-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-153-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
usage: paste [-h]
paste: error: unrecognized arguments: -s -d  
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-163-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-155-generic
 linux-image-3.13.0-155-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-161-generic
 linux-image-3.13.0-161-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-162-generic
 linux-image-3.13.0-162-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-163-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
imtiyaz@Baka:~$
```

#### output of df command:

```
imtiyaz@Baka:~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev              497644        4    497640   1% /dev
tmpfs             101544     1240    100304   2% /run
/dev/sda1      239212096 14561316 212476396   7% /
none                   4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none              507712    16036    491676   4% /run/shm
none              102400       44    102356   1% /run/user
imtiyaz@Baka:~$
```

Comment: @ubfan1 i don't remembered but while ago when i was stuck in grub rescue so i pasted many packages to another boot

Comment: Please post the output of the command df   That should let us know if you have a boot partition, and how full it is.

Comment: @ubfan1 i have added the output of `df` in question

Comment: OK, so not a full partition, just some missing files you probably manually deleted.  Same solution applies as in the posted link (give the package manager an empty file if it complains about one missing when trying to purge the package).  There may be more elegant solutions, but you'd need to look in the Full Disk questions.

Comment: you mean i have to do something like this? `sudo echo >/boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-155-generic` and then reconfigure the missing file `sudo dpkg-reconfigure thepackage`

Comment: That should do it.  Keep doing it for any problems of missing files and the package manager will eventually finish.

Comment: sorry but for `sudo dpkg-reconfigure 'what should i write here? initrd-img-3.13.0-155-generic or linux-image-3.13.0-155-generic'??`

Comment: @ubfan1 `sudo dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-3.13.0-155-generic` returns error: not fully installed or broken

Comment: Keep tryhing the sudo apt-get -f install , fixing the "missing" errors until the package mananger is in a consistent state.  linux-image-3.13.0-155-generic is going to be removed, not reconfigured anyway.